# IntelliJ 14 Idea not refresh resource bundle when project was built

Tags: java, spring, jsp, intellij-idea, resourcebundle

I migrated my project to IntelliJ 14 IDEA from STS 3.6.3 as STS keeping crash with not really clear exception.

I can configure IntelliJ to make my project works, but when I tried to modify my resources bundle property files to add some lines in that file to help my JSP to generate content, I found my IntelliJ not refresh when I build my project and deploy it on Tomcat server.

My project's Spring MVC (Web layer) original generated by using MyEclipse CRUD that came with SiteMesh and spring-dojo support. All web page (JSP) contents were put in resources bundle property file to support page content customisation.

When I migrate the project to IntelliJ, the original resources bundle was brought over, and I can see it siting in my
    "/$MODULE_DIR$/resources/bundles"

file name as "firm entity-resources.properties"

I can edit it and Synchronise it. I added some lines like:

```
firmentity.person.title.options=Mr.,Ms.,Mrs.,Dr.,Other
firmentity.firmstatus.options=New,Engaged,OutServiced
```

I can call by using

```
<fmt:setBundle basename="bundles.firmentity-resources"/> 
<fmt:message key="firmentity.person.title.options" var="title_t" scope="session" />
<fmt:message key="firmentity.firmstatus.options" var="firmstatus_t" scope="session" />
```

in my JSP. and then retrieve it by using

```
<fmt:message key="firmentity.title"/>
```

this is very common usage in JSP.

I tried set it up in my OzsscWeb.iml with some very little modify to support dojo, but I never make my resources bundle refresh, very time I save my editing and redeploy my application to server, IntelliJ always take my original property file when I first migrated it from STS with out any newly edited content refreshing.

I totally lost my direction to my next step. Any one have such experience pleas help!!!

Any advice and suggestion welcome. With Plenty appreciation.

Have a happy Chinese New Year! Guys.

**Edit**

It is always siting in my "Sources Folders" in my "Project structure" Modules setting. I tried put it in my "Resources Folders" in my Modules setting, and press "Apply" and "OK" to make it works. But unfortunately, Every time I re-open my "Project Structure", it sit back to my "Sources Folders" again. I believe where is some thing mis-configured to it not work well.

This my IntelliJ config file OzsscWeb.iml.  web-facet looks like:

```
<facet type="web" name="Web">
  <configuration>
    <descriptors>
      <deploymentDescriptor name="web.xml" url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml" />
    </descriptors>
    <webroots>
      <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/WebContent" relative="/" />
    </webroots>
    <sourceRoots>
      <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" />
      <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/generated" />
      <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/resources" />
    </sourceRoots>
  </configuration>
</facet>
```

And there is some thing linked to it as:

```
<component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_8" inherit-compiler-output="false">
<output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/classes" />
<output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/test-classes" />
<content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/resources" type="java-resource" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
</content>
<orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
<orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
</component>
```

It was specified as "java-resource". I tried to change it to some thing else, but seems it not work.

**Edit**

It is not a Java EE project, it is pure Spring MVC project, but it will call EJB client in @controller by using EJB injection (was defined as java bean). EJBs was deployed in WebLogic 12C server (runs in separate machine) with remote interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the `resources` folder is not being included in the module's sources list. Right-click on the project and select "Open Module Settings". In the "Modules" section, select the module in question and verify that the `resources` folder is listed on the right. If it is not, select the folder in the left pane and click on the "Resources" button above.

Comment: It is always siting in my "Sources Folders" in my "Project structure" Modules setting. I tried put it in my "Resources Folders" in my Modules setting, and press "Apply" and "OK" to make it works. But unfortunately, Every time I re-open my "Project Structure", it sit back to my "Sources Folders" again. I believe where is some thing mis-configured to it not work well.

Comment: Hmm... Yeah, that's definitely a problem. Since this is a web application, anything in "Sources" would be written to ```WEB-INF/classes```. Do you have any other file types anywhere in that directory hierarchy (starting at 'resources'), or is it all .properties files?

Comment: There are only Property files and XML files sitting in that directory. No Java sources at all.

Comment: Is this project configured as a JavaEE project? You can check by right-clicking on the project, then selecting "Add Framework Support...". If that all looks right, then try opening the module settings again and inspect the artifact. The artifact should contain a ```WEB-INF/classes``` folder with the compilation output and a ```'[ModuleName]' module: 'Web' facet resources``` source. If the latter is missing, right-click in the layout and select "Add Copy of" > "JavaEE Facet Resources".

Comment: If the module settings dialog still doesn't seem to keep your changes, try right-clicking on the ```resources``` folder and select "Mark Directory As" > "Resources Root"

Comment: thank you for your reply. It is not a Java EE project, it is pure Spring MVC project, is works fine in STS. but it will call EJB client in controller by using EJB injection (was defined as java bean). EJBs was deployed in WebLogic 12C server (runs in separate machine) with remote interface. All the back end logic is working in perfect order, only the bundle resources not refresh in IntelliJ build, I believe there is some thing wrong in configure, make it not watch my property file editing.

Comment: The project was configured to support web and spring framework. there is nothing else.

Comment: I tried to mark resources folder as an "Resources Root", but again, when I save it and re-load it back, it was re-set back to "Resources".

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that your changes are _never_ being deployed to the server, or are you saying that they are not being deployed _automatically_ when they're modified?

Comment: My changes are never being deployed to the server!! It always taken my first migrated version bundle resource property to deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can find quick solution for that problem. Instead of spend lots time to fix that issue. I re-installed STS 3.6.3 by deleted everything come with STS, make a clean installation, and roll back to STS. do re-configuration. it works fine in STS.